# IntelliJ: custom code generation templates

Tags: intellij-idea, code-generation, code-templates

How can I define custom code generation like Getters/Setters in IntelliJ. I took a look on their [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#customize-templates) but they don't specify where I can do this. The code I would like IntelliJ to generate for me is like below:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String username;

   //I want IntelliJ to propose me to generate this after Alt+Insert
   public Person withName(String name){
      setName(name);
      return this;
   }
   //and this 
   public Person withUsername(String username){
      setUsername(username);
      return this;
   }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: This can't be done by modifying the settings. You need to write a plugin that will add an action to the Generate menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press alt+insert you can click Getter and Setter. There are Getter template and Setter template drop-downs that you can select. Click the ... and you can create new templates.
[image]

It appears you're trying to follow the [builder pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern). IntelliJ already has a setter template for this called "Builder". You can select it from the setter drop-down and you should be good.

Comment: I dont see what you mean by " Click the ..." since there isn't this proposition

Comment: I added a picture. There's also documentation about this at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getter-and-setter-templates-dialog.html. What version of IDEA are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the default setter template as I use lombok. Works fine!